# sed -i does not work when run with sudo

Tags: sed

The file I want to modify belongs to `root`. I want to change this file with a sudo-er

```
sudo sed -i 's/Accept .* LC_\*$/& GIT_*/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

(trying to append `GIT_*` to the `Accept` sshd config directive)

But the file remains unchanged:

```
$ grep Accept /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `.*` after `Accept`:

```
sudo sed -i 's/Accept.* .* LC_\*$/& GIT_*/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: That is partly true. That was supposed to be a white space `Accept\w.*` (and since there was a tab, that was the problem) Thanks!